# QProgressBar text format as time

Tags: c++, qt, qprogressbar

I was wondering either there is any easy way of displaying current and maximum value of `QProgressBar` as seconds in `HH:mm:ss` format. Currently my format is `%v/%m`, is there a way to show it as time?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QProgressBar::setFormat(QString)`; you can use any text you want, just convert your time to QString.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressbar.html#format-prop